# textFieldShouldBeginEditing being trigged by the wrong textfield

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitextfield

I have two textfields `dateNTextField` and `prenomTextField` which only dateNTextField's delegate is set :

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == self.dateNTextField.tag {
        print(textField.tag)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
}
```

However, I get the same result for the click on both textfields even that they have different tags!
Any help would be very appreciated.

Edit:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{ 
 self.dateNTextField.delegate = self
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(chooseImage(recognizer:)));
self.picker.delegate = self
profilImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
profilImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
tapGesture.delegate = self
self.dateNTextField.accessibilityIdentifier = "date"
self.prenomTextField.accessibilityIdentifier = "prenom"}
```

Comment: and what happens with this :     `if textField == self.dateNTextField {` ?

Comment: I get the same results.

Comment: basically you want to hide keyboard as soon as user clicks the `dateNTextField` ?

Comment: Yes, or the user clicks on the Next button on the keyboard when they finish editing prenomTextField.

Comment: It will be better to see initialization code

Comment: how about `dateNTextField.editable = false` in viewdidload?

Comment: What you exactly want to do on 2 text field?

Comment: Place breakpoints in the code, and see if the code within the `if` statement is run on both textFields. If it is only run once, the problem will be elsewhere in the code, and just happens to be giving the same result.

Comment: @Evgeniy Gushchin I just updated my post

Comment: @OmarChaabouni Did you bind textfield delegates??

Comment: Possibly (if you use storyboard) you bind one text field to both IBOutlets (dateNTextField and prenomTextField)

Comment: @Evgeniy Gushchin nope I checked. @ the_dahiya_boy yes.

Comment: So I suggest to set breakpoint on IF statement and take look to your text fields. 
When you stop on breakpoint write in console `po dateNTextField` and `po prenomTextField `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `return true` statement inside your `if` condition.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.dateNTextField{
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text fields have equal tags.
Try to compare text fields instead of tags

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.dateNTextField{
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: They have different tags. And I have already tried ` if textField == self.dateNTextField{` but same thing

Comment: @OmarChaabouni without initialization code it's very difficult to understand what's going wrong. Also, if you don't want to use text field as editable element, why you don't use UILabel instead?

Comment: @OmarChaabouni Above answer is perfect. So make sure your both textField is binded with delegates.

Comment: UILabel would work if it is intended to never be edited, or just set editing to false in the first place to avoid this func from running all together

Comment: @EvgeniyGushchin Sometimes we need to use `textField` not `label` eg. he wanted to trigger some event on textfield did begin so he not gonna take label and for symmetricity he have 5 textfield where user give input and for one thing is not take label.

Comment: @EthanHumphries What if he going to add child VC in this class on click on textField. If he disable userIntraction as per you then it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could set identifiers (`dateNTextField.accessibilityIdentifier` for example), rather than using tags.

Initialise both the textFields and set their identifiers right away and then just refer to them by their ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tag of text field you should use this :

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.dateNTextField {
        print(textField.tag)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
}
```

It will work for you.